# Using commons-configuration2 and commons-beanutils-1.9 with Apache spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

My application is using commons-configuration2 and commons-beanutils1.9, but when I try to use my application jars for spark streaming jobs it is throwing following exception.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBeanUtilsBean(BeanHelper.java:631)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.(BeanHelper.java:89)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:185)

And here is my build.sbt

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-configuration2" % "2.0",
      "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.2",
      "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.10" % "2.0.1",
      "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.4.0",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.0" % "provided",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
      "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.61",
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.6.2",
      "org.jasypt" % "jasypt" % "1.9.2",
      "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.8",
      "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.3",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.3" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-beanutils"))

    )

    dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4",
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.6.2",
      "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.6.2",
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-configuration2" % "2.0",
      "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.2"
    )

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

How do I make sure that it is using commons-beanutils-1.9.2 instead of commons-beanutils-1.7 or commons-beanutils-core-1.8 which are part of hadoop-common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding unwanted jars in project's settings works for me:

```
...
.settings(assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
    val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value

    val excludes = Set(
      "commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar",
      "commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar",
      "commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar"
    )
    cp.filter{jar => excludes.contains(jar.data.getName)}
  })
```

Comment: Hi Denis, 

Thanks for the response, but for me it is still giving the exception at runtime. I check PropertyUtilsBean class from the uber jar generated from assembly and it is corresponding to the commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar only, but at runtime when I do spark-submit then it is complaining about addBeanIntrospector method. How do we tell spark to use the class file from uber jar instead of one comes with spark environment at runtime?

Comment: Did you try shading (i.e. basically renaming package during assembly creation and fixing all the references to use the alternate package name)? It may work in this case. Take a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading for more details. 

Unfortunately it doesn't always work, e.g. if jar contains code that depends on the original package name. In particular, it didn't help me with using two different AWS SDK versions in the same project. I solved this by writing a custom class loader for my library to keep the same symbols in different versions of the same library separate.

Comment: Thanks Denis, for your suggestion to use shading, it is working fine after I applied shading for the specified jars/packages. I have one more question, can we apply shading on the packages contained in the jars in lib folder of sbt project? I have to upload the application jars to internal maven repository to apply shading on those jars. If it is possible to apply on the jars    placed in lib folder, then it would solve my problem without uploading onto nexus repository.